# How do I pull a single branch from all remotes with libgit2sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I would like to run through all remotes in my repo and pull from the same branch in each remote.
I can't figure out how to achieve this with libgit2sharp because I can't seem to find a way to pull from a specific branch.

I can do a fetch from a specific remote, but not a pull.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit?  You want to merge multiple remote branches into your current branch?

Comment: I have the same branch `master` on multiple remotes. And I want to do a `git pull remotename master` for each remote. So yes I want to merge multiple remote branches into the current branch.